# Why does Microsoft Edge have a url here

Tags: microsoft-edge

I've simplified it down to this html:

```
<html>
<body>

Test_170185.00000

</body>
</html>
```

On Edge I get:

[image]

On Chrome and Firefox I get something like:

[image]

When I inspect on any of them I just get the plain html back.
What is going on here?

Here's a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/dtrubb5z/

In Edge (41.16299.371.0):
[image]

In Chrome (or anything else) :
[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `Microsoft Edge 41.16299.248.0` / `Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299`

Comment: My version of Microsoft Edge:  41.16299.371.0 and EdgeHTML 16.16299.

Comment: Also strangely, many other numbers don't cause the issue, but some others do.

Comment: For me, it happens in this jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/dtrubb5z/

Also, only in Edge.

Comment: I have now tested that jsfiddle on multiple computers with the 41.16299.371.0 version of Edge.  They all show the issue.

Comment: I have updated my browser to `Microsoft Edge 41.16299.371.0` / `Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299` and still cannot reproduce it (whether with the jsfiddle or localhost:8000) Could be an Edge extension or the cache?

Comment: Well, thanks for trying.  Any machine I go to at work shows this issue in Edge.  So far, everyone is running this version.  No other browser, including IE shows this issue.  I don't have any extensions installed.  I then did a check on a computer that has never been on this network, and ran it from their home.  The jsfiddle, shows the blue underlined numbers in Edge.

Comment: Looks like you may be running into a behavior that Edge triggers when Skype is installed. Potentially the question is a duplicate of [this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978346/remove-microsoft-edges-phone-number-styling)

Comment: Mike G, you're a genius.  That's it!  The <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> tag seems to work.  Seems stupid that the default is to take numbers and assume they are telephone numbers.  Will have to add that to the header for every page in the entire app, but at least it's fixed.  Thanks.  If you post that answer, I'll approve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Microsoft Edge's phone number styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978346/remove-microsoft-edges-phone-number-styling)

Comment: The answer might be a duplicate.  But I would have never found that answer, because, in my mind, the data did not resemble a phone number.

Comment: @cbaconnier What Edge considers telephone-number-like, depends on the regional settings. If the asker is in a country where `170185.00000` seems like a typical length of a phone number, and the prefix does not make it impossible that it is a telephone number, and so on, then Edge will make a phone link out of it. But in your country, phone numbers may look different. Try creating a web page with "plain" text containing a number that looks like a typical phone number in your country (Switzerland?). Edge might link that. Or maybe Edge will fail to linkify anything in your particular region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edge detects it as a phone number and decides to style it.  The only way I know to disable it is this:

```
<html>
<body>

<p x-ms-format-detection="none">Test_170185.00000</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Their documentation is here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn337007

Comment: Mike G pointed out this questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978346/remove-microsoft-edges-phone-number-styling  which talks about putting this in the header of the page:  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">  This does seem to work as well.