# ag grid column value displays hyperlink for one of the data in Edge browser

Tags: angular, hyperlink, microsoft-edge, ag-grid

I am using ag grid in my angular application, below is the version in package.json file.

```
  "ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0",
  "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
  "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.2.0",
```

I see a strange behavior in Edge version 42.17134.1.1, as one of the cell value (xyz **[Jul 2019 120.000](https://stackoverlow.com)** abc) in Edge displays hyperlink.

the value displays fine in other browsers. Why this strange behavior in Edge?

What is the solution to fix this issue in angular/ag-grid?

Answer (score 3):

That's the behavior of Edge browser. It will be displayed even if you don't display it in [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).

You can get rid of it by adding this meta tag in the header of your pages.

```html
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Reference: [Remove Microsoft Edge's phone number styling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978712/1417185)