# IE color issue with phone number structure

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am facing an issue, might seems stupid

Here is link

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p style="color:#fff">P: 888/987-1144</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So in IE 11 the color of number is blue. I want to change it , when tried with inline css. It does not affect.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this.

```
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the browser is applying its own styling as it matches the pattern of a phone number making it clickable for phones.

This post covers it:
[Remove Microsoft Edge's phone number styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978346/remove-microsoft-edges-phone-number-styling)

Answer (score 1):

User could use the following methods to disable phone number detection in Microsoft Edge browser:

• Disable phone number detection for an entire document. Add:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

• Disable phone number detection on the specific problematic content:

```
<p x-ms-format-detection="none" style="color:#fff">P: 888/987-1144</p>
```

More detail information, please check [Phone number format recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn265018(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)